# Why do we place jQuery in the header?

Tags: jquery

Every tutorial I come across says to make sure you call jQuery in the header:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
```

Even if you only want to use it on one page. Why would you want jQuery to sit in your header and load on every page of your website if you only want to use it on one?

I'm a noob so just asking.

Comment: Each page has its own header (unless you make one that you include everywhere). Including jQuery in one page's header will not necessarily include it in another page's header.

Comment: @Permou IT depends on what he means by header.  If he means the <head> section of the page you are right.  If he is taking about some kind of server side header like an asp.net master page then what he says makes sense.

Comment: I'm actually speaking in regards to Wordpress' header.php file. I don't want to mess with the core file but I don't know why everyone advises to put it in the header. Maybe I should ask the WP forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason is to guarantee that any javascript function that might fire up on your document before is fully loaded and that are dependent on jQuery, can execute without problems.

If you are sure this is not the case with your page, you can perfectly include jQuery at the bottom of the page. In fact, it may improve load time of the page, and this applies to any javascript library.

Answer (score 4):

Because we don't.

I myself only include necessary script tags in the header.

Of course if every tutorial saying you should include it so you do not encounter trouble with that.

Answer (score 3):

Because you might as well, once it has been downloaded it will be cached by the browser especially when it links to a CDN version of the code because the browser will hopefully have it cached already from another site.

Comment: The odds of having it cached from another site aren't very good - http://statichtml.com/2011/google-ajax-libraries-caching.html. Also unless the caching headers are set correctly then the browser will make an "if-modified-since" request to the server for every reference to it.

Comment: Well that's the theory I can't pretend I did any research into the odds other than i remember a not very scientific survey that most of the top 100 alexa sites used the Google CDN.  Most CDNs do set the headers correctly they have a very far future expiry.

Comment: 'because you might as well' - what kind of answer is that? We don't do things in JavaScript because we might as well. We do things because they are the correct thing to do, or we do not do them at all. Putting scripts at the bottom of the page is best practice in any case

Answer (score 0):

Adding jQuery to the header is not the same as adding jQuery to the header of all pages. You can add jQuery to the header only for a single page. It depends on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As many script elements as possible should be moved to the **bottom** of the page for performance reasons. This is [standard practice](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) and has been for some time.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can make it load in the header of just one page if you want to.
2. If it loads on one page, it will be cached in browser memory so there is no problem putting it on subsequently visited pages
3. If you use a CDN it will most likely already be cached in browser memory
4. It should be loaded in the head so that it is loaded *before* the code that depends on it

Comment: Point 4 is incorrect. Code doesn't have to be in the head of the page to ensure it is loaded before other dependant code. With proper load events JS is not called until the DOM has loaded anyway